# Array of object as String to Array of object (jSON)?

Tags: php

I'm trying to convert this string :

```
$json = '[{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}, {"a":6,"b":7,"c":8,"d":9,"e":10}]';
```

To an array of object. I've tried :

```
$test = json_decode($json, true);
echo sizeof($test); //traces 2 !
echo $test[0]["a"]; //doesn't echo anything!
```

How do i convert in PHP a json string to an array of object ??

Comment: Assuming that json is parsed into an array of objects, try `$test[0]->a`

Comment: Thanks, you should have made a "real" answer ;)

Comment: Ok, I posted it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that json is parsed into an array of objects, try

```
$test[0]->a
```

You can see this easily with

```
print_r($test)
```

which would output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [a] => 1
            [b] => 2
            [c] => 3
            [d] => 4
            [e] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [a] => 6
            [b] => 7
            [c] => 8
            [d] => 9
            [e] => 10
        )

)
```

Comment: OP needs to remove the second parameter so that his code is: `$test = json_decode($json);`

Comment: For clarification, if the above output were the OP's output, then accessing an element via `$test[0]['a']` should work. However, if the second dimension were `stdClass Object`s instead of `Array` as per your output, then accessing an element via `$test[0]->a` would work.

Comment: I tested his json_decode and the output is mine. The second level is object, not array.

Answer (score 1):

json_decode returns an [object](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php).  To convert the object to an array:

```
$test = (array)json_decode($json, true);
```